# How to display the group by in access database using two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here I want to display the family member where the members house no is same and also address is same. I am using the access database.here is my query

```
SELECT 
   voter.SrNo, voter.YadiNo, voter.fullname, voter.houseno, voter.address, 
   voter.Gender, voter.Age, voter.CardNo
FROM voter 
WHERE 
   (((voter.YadiNo) Between 1 And 1) 
    AND ((voter.houseno) In (SELECT [houseno] FROM [Voter] As Tmp 
                             GROUP BY [houseno]  
                             HAVING Count(houseno) >= 5 and Count(houseno) <= 5))) 
ORDER BY voter.houseno;
```

but in this query it show same house but display the different address.

I want to show same house no and same address .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For each group of `houseno`, `address` what values do you want to select for the other columns `SrNo`, `YadiNo`, `fullname` , ... etc??

Comment: put sample data to the table voter !!! && expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must change you having clause
   HAVING COUNT(houseno) >=5 AND COUNT(houseno) <=5
This is wrong, only count(houseno) equal 5 will be selected.
Please attach a example of data what you use to finding out answer of your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
select voter.SrNo, voter.YadiNo, voter.fullname, voter.houseno, voter.address, voter.Gender, voter.Age, voter.CardNo
FROM voter
where voter.YadiNo IN (select v.voter.YadiNo from voter v where 
(v.houseno = (select vt.houseno from voter vt where vt.YadiNo= 1) and 
(v.address = (select vtv.address from voter vt where vt.YadiNo =1))
```

I didnt compile this one. Just logic i provided..

Comment: Hello sir i try this query but not give the output which is i want.